# Intertwined vs interwind

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *intertwined* and *interwind*? Especially when used talking about abstract subject matters.

For example, should one say: "love begins when admiration and trust .........." interwind or intertwine?

Comment: Hi Earthling!  Can you be more specific as to what is unclear to you after referencing the definitions for these words?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Let me know if the example helps.

Comment: *Have you looked up each word in a dictionary?* What did you find? What are the differences between the two definitions? When using either word abstractly, you're using it as a *metaphor*, so there's no right or wrong, there's simply the particular sense you wish to convey. NB *interwind* is uncommon...

Comment: What about entwine?  "Love begins when admiration and trust entwine"

Answer (score 3):

I can find "intertwined" in more dictionaries than "interwind" (which my spell-check flags up as wrong), but a quick lookup on [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interwind) reveals

> **interwind** (verb)
>
> intertwine, intervolve

and on [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interwind)

> **interwind** (verb)
>
> to wind together; intertwine.

In conclusion, they are interchangeable in meaning, but "intertwined" appears to be more frequently used.